# Client laravel-echo does not respond to server events

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-echo

I'm trying to build my docker sample to work with php8.2, laravel10, websockets and redis.
I have already prepared all the necessary docker images and combined them with the Caddy proxy.
I also used horizon to debug my broadcasting (in another docker container)
This is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  ### workspace ##################################
  workspace:
    build:
      context: ./workspace
      args:
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
        - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
        - YARN_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION}
        - APP_CODE_PATH=${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    environment:
      - APP_CODE_PATH=${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    volumes:
      - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    tty: true
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
  
  ### php-fpm ##############################################
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./php-fpm
      args:
        - APP_CODE_PATH=${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    expose:
      - "9000"
    depends_on:
      - workspace
      - db
      - redis
      - laravel-echo-server
    networks:
      - backend

  ### caddy ###############################################
  caddy:
    image: caddy:2.2.1
    environment:
      - CADDY_HOST_LABEL=${CADDY_HOST_LABEL}
      - APP_CODE_PATH=${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
      - caddy_data:/data
      - caddy_config:/config
      - ./caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
    ports:
      - "${CADDY_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
      - "${CADDY_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  ### db ##################################################
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    build:
      context: ./db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/db:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
    networks:
      - backend

  ### redis ###############################################
  redis:
    build: ./redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/redis:/data
    expose:
      - "6379"
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
    networks:
      - backend

  ### websockets ##########################################
  laravel-echo-server:
    image: oanhnn/laravel-echo-server:latest
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      LARAVEL_ECHO_SERVER_AUTH_HOST: http://example.com
      LARAVEL_ECHO_SERVER_DEBUG:     'true'
      LARAVEL_ECHO_SERVER_DB:        redis
      REDIS_HOST:     redis
      REDIS_PORT:     6379
      REDIS_PREFIX:   ""
      REDIS_DB:       0
    expose:
      - "6001"
    ports:
     - 6001:6001
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - backend

  ### horizon #############################################
  horizon:
    build:
      context: ./horizon
      args:
        - APP_CODE_PATH=${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - backend

version: '3'

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:

volumes:
  mysql:
  redis:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
```

I configured everything correctly and my messages are successfully delivered, they are present in the debug console of laravel-echo-server, they are successfully displayed in laravel-horizon (there are no error messages anywhere, or no one is reporting that the behavior is incorrect)

Now I have started setting up my client. I have an electron + frontend application in React. According to the documentation, I installed "socket.io-client" and "laravel-echo" using npm.
I have configured socket-io like this:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
  });
} else {
  console.log("IO ERROR")
}

window.Echo.channel(`laravel_database_translation.1`)
.listen('.App\\Events\\TranslationEvent', (e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

I connect to a websocket, I see ping/pong requests happening on the Internet tab(in f12).
But when on the server side, using the console command, I dispatch my event - in my console I do not receive any information about this.

I tried different ways to connect to my channel, removed "laravel_database_" from the .channel('') method, changed the naming options for the event in .listen('*'). But I couldn’t catch the event via websockets.
Before, I tried to do the same with local pusher, but also failed.Ыo I thought that switching to socket-io would help me - which I was wrong about. I'm pretty sure the problem is with my docker containers since I'm not a Dockerfile configurator. but it seems that it should work now, maybe the problem is different.
My event on laravel:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TranslationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels, Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public $id, public $message)
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('translation.'.$this->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also did it locally in laravel workspace. I installed node/npm, connected SocketIO and laravel-echo in main.js, connected them to the page and waited. No, my events are still not being listened to by my laravel-echo, I do not know what I am doing wrong, my hands are starting to give up, I suspect that there is some kind of dependency between the laravel-echo-server and laravel-echo-client versions, and also incompatibility of some versions with SocketIO, since I I work with php8.2.
Laravel Echo Server: version 1.6.3 + socket.io: 2.3.0
Laravel Echo version: 1.15.3
socket.io-client: 4.7.3

Comment: I change socket.io-client version for compability with server to 2.3.0, but it still dont work. I'm running out of energy to do this with Laravel and PHP, my last attempt will be to collect all this without Docker, on my virtual Ubuntu in one image, and even if it doesn’t work, I’ll run out of time to figure it out

Comment: Now I saw new logs in my laravel-echo-server, it seems I have hope (after changing the version of laravel-echo-client)
```
[2024-01-05T23:19:43.876Z] - R3F_RUIogh5dPI8bAACT left channel: laravel_database_translation (transport close)
2024-01-06 02:19:44 [2024-01-05T23:19:44.403Z] - LQHBxM5DCMyya1BEAACU joined channel: laravel_database_translation
2024-01-06 02:20:31 Channel: laravel_database_translation
2024-01-06 02:20:31 Event: App\Events\TranslationEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally!
After countless attempts to rebuild the Docker container, I finally identified a bug - the incompatibility of laravel-echo-server with the local version of laravel-echo. **Use version 2.3.0 of laravel-echo** and you will succeed!

Console log, which I waited more 10 hours :')
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbsCR.png
PS
if you use 2.3.0, then know that at that time it only supported the following code format:

```js
window.Echo.channel('laravel_database_translation') // <== only full name
.listen('.App\\Events\\TranslationEvent', (e) => { // <== only full name
    console.log(e);
});
```